# Kill a YARN application through REST api return Unauthorized by remote user dr.who

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn

`curl -u hadoop:123456 -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-type: application/json" -v -X PUT -d '{"state": "KILLED"}' "http://host:8088/ws/v1/cluster/apps/application_1575020200992_1673895/state"`

I was already add the username and password, but return：

```
Unauthorized attempt to kill appid application_1575020200992_1673895 by remote user dr.who
```

What's dr.who ？

Answer (score 0):

I figure out... add the user.name query string parameter.

like this:

```
curl -u hadoop:123456 -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-type: application/json" -v -X PUT -d '{"state": "KILLED"}' "http://host:8088/ws/v1/cluster/apps/application_1575020200992_1673895/state?user.name=hadoop"
```

http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/HttpAuthentication.html